# Problema con fprintf al escribir en un fichero en C

Tags: c

Muy buenas!

Tengo un problema con el siguiente ejercicio: contar vocales, consonantes y espacios en blanco que hay en un fichero cuyo nombre introduce el usuario por teclado, dando por hecho que en el fichero hay escrito el texto:
"Este es un texto de
prueba para el Examen
Extraordinario de Programacion", pero podría ser otro cualquiera.

Pues utilizo fprintf y lo que hace es incluirme el texto y al final unos espacios que no me explico de dónde salen, y luego no me cuentan bien las variables. Sin embargo, si omito el fprintf y escribo en un fichero llamado, por ejemplo, prueba.txt, el texto anterior por defecto y escribo su nombre en el programa sí que me cuenta todo correctamente (además lo abro como a+ para evitar problemas de sobreescritura con w+).

Dejo aquí el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
    FILE *f;
    char nombreFichero[20];
    char c;
    int a=0, e=0, i=0, o=0, u=0, consonante=0, espacio=0;
    
    printf ("Introduzca el nombre del fichero: ");
    fgets (nombreFichero,20,stdin);
    nombreFichero[strlen(nombreFichero)-1]='\0';
    
    f = fopen(nombreFichero,"w+");
    
    fprintf (f, "Este es un texto de");
    fprintf (f, "prueba para el Examen");
    fprintf (f, "Extraordinario de Programacion");
    
    while (c != EOF){
        c = tolower(fgetc(f));
        
        printf ("%c", c);
        
        switch (c){
            case 'a': a++; break;
            case 'e': e++; break;
            case 'i': i++; break;
            case 'o': o++; break;
            case 'u': u++; break;
            case ' ': espacio++; break;
            default: consonante++;
        }
        
        if (c=='\n' || c=='\0' || c==EOF){
            consonante--;
        }
    }
    
    printf ("Resumen del archivo '%s':\n", nombreFichero);
    printf ("Numero de aes: %i\n", a);
    printf ("Numero de ees: %i\n", e);
    printf ("Numero de ies: %i\n", i);
    printf ("Numero de oes: %i\n", o);
    printf ("Numero de ues: %i\n", u);
    printf ("Numero de consonantes: %i\n", consonante);
    printf ("Numero de espacios en blanco: %i", espacio);
    
    fclose (f);
        
    return 0;
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2):

Cuando tu escribes en el archivo estás modificando el puntero de acceso al mismo. Si no reseteas ese cursor para que apunte al inicio del archivo, cuando realices operaciones de lectura es altamente probable que obtengas resultados extraños.

Para resetar el puntero interno del archivo basta con usar `fseek`:

```
fseek(0, SEEK_SET);

while (c != EOF){
    // ...
```

Aunque sería más conveniente cerrar el archivo y abrirlo en modo solo lectura:

```
fclose(f);
f = fopen(nombreFichero,"r");

while (c != EOF){
    // ...
```

Comment: Es verdad, no caí en cerrar y abrir de nuevo, qué bruto xddd. En fin, lo pruebo así porque fseek no lo hemos dado y no me permiten usarlo. Muchas gracias! :D

Comment: Se me olvidó ponerlo, pero se solucionó de esta forma!